# In IE browser always load the old data from the brower

Tags: javascript, jsp

In IE browser always loads old data from the browser history.For getting the latest data i need to clear the browser history always.

How to load the new data always?
Is there a way to clear the browsing history using javascript?

This seems to be because for the temporary internet files and website files

I have tried several methods like

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='-1'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

> ```
> response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
>       response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
>       response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
> ```

```
var numberOfEntries = window.history.length;
    window.history.go(-numberOfEntries); 

    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }

    window.history.replaceState();

      window.location.replace(document.url);
```

Nothing seems to be working

Comment: Code how you are doing it? (Caching headers especially)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the page each time it loads in some way to see if the 
browser stops caching the old page.

You might try placing a hidden input element in your page and then updating its value on each
page load to see if it is enough to force the browser to display the newest version of your page.

here is link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/nu1jpvjh/1/

html part:

```
 <input id="version" type = "hidden" value = "1">
```

jquery part:

```
      //the highest number you want to retrieve randomly
      var upperLimit = 1000;

     //get random number between 1 and 1000
    //change upperlimit above to increase or 
   //decrease range
    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * upperLimit) + 1);    


  //update the #version input box value
  $("#version").val(randomNum);
```